# Recursive htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, recursion

I use this htaccess rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}\-[A-Z]{2})/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}\-[A-Z]{2})/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&controller=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}\-[A-Z]{2})/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&controller=$2&p1=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}\-[A-Z]{2})/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&controller=$2&p1=$3&p2=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}\-[A-Z]{2})/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&controller=$2&p1=$3&p2=$4&p3=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}\-[A-Z]{2})/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&controller=$2&p1=$3&p2=$4&p3=$5&p4=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}\-[A-Z]{2})/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&controller=$2&p1=$3&p2=$4&p3=$5&p4=$6&p5=$7 [L]
```

As you can see, the logic of this is that **the first parameter is language formated (ie: `en` or `en-US`), the second parameter is a the controller** and the rest are parameters are named as `'p'` concat `n`, where `n` is the order number of the parameter *(p1/p2/p3)*.

Now, I want to add something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,})/?$ /index.php?defaultcontroller=true&p1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,})/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?defaultcontroller=true&p1=$1&p2=$2 [L]
// And so on ...
```

This is trying that **if the first parameter is not language formated, the controller is a default controller** and the first parameter is `p1`, the second is `p2` and so on. But this has three problems:

- `([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,})` is not a negation of `([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}\-[A-Z]{2})`. URLs like `http://example.com/e` or `http://example.com/3n` won't match any pattern (they should match the second).
- I am going to end up with more than 10 lines.
- I have a limit of parameters. `http://example.com/es-US/controller/p1/p2/p3/p4/p5/p6` won't match any pattern.

So, please, could you help me to reduce this to a *(kind of)* recursive code having only two lines (one for the first parameter is language formated and one for the first parameter non-laguage formated)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following 1 liner :

```
    RewriteRule ^(en|en-US)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^]*)/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&controller=$2&p1=$3&p2=$4&p3=$5&p4=$6&p5=$7 [L]
```

Comment: I guess this makes optional the parameters. Nice.
I can't use `(en|en-US)`, but the `([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}\-[A-Z]{2})` because I have to accept many language codes. Also, Do you know how to negate `([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}\-[A-Z]{2})`?